# Extracting Data from Nested Lists with exception (Magic: the Gathering Data), Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary, indexing

New to Python. This question relies on the `MTGTools` package, located [here](https://github.com/EskoSalaka/mtgtools).

**Background**
Magic: The Gathering is a trading card game in which certain types of cards (creatures) have the attribute "Power".

Using the package `MTGTools`, it is easy to download card data and then access the power of a card through this syntax:

```
PCardList.creatures().cards.data[0].power_num
```

`PCardList` is a list of `PCards`, which "[are] a simple persistent dataclass representing Magic: the Gathering cards with their characteristic attributes."

`creatures()` filters the list for creatures (which are the only cards with "power").

`cards.data[0].power_num`  returns the numerical value of the first creature in the `PCardlist`, so "power_num" is an attribute of the `PCard` indexed by `cards.data[0]`.

However, the developers have recently started printing multi-faced cards. The "power" values for each face are contained in a *dictionary* that is an *attribute* of the `PCard`. So, to access the power of the front face of a card, we use the following syntax:

```
PCardList.creatures().cards.data[0].card_faces[0].get('power_num')
```

If the card only has one face, `card_faces` is {NoneType}, but if it is double faced, it is a list of two dictionaries, where "power" is accessed by `get('power_num')`

**Problem**

I am trying to make a list of the power of each card in a `PCardList`. The following list comprehension works perfectly for single-faced cards:

```
[PCardList.creatures().cards.data[i].power_num for i in range(0,len(PCardList.creatures()))]
```

However, if the `PCardList` contains a multifaced card, it will return something like: `[1.0, 2.0, None, 1.0, 3.0]`.

What I would like is to create a means of checking whether or not the `PCard` is multifaced, and if it is, return the "power" of each face as a separate entry in the list. So if our multifaced card in the example above had power = 5.0 on the front and power = 0.0 on the back, our new list would be: `[1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0]`.

**Attempt**

```
pow_list = []
for x in PCardList.creatures().cards.data:
if x.card_faces is None:
    pow_list.append(x.power_num)
else:
    pow_list.append(x.card_faces[0].get('power_num')) #add first face
    pow_list.append(x.card_faces[1].get('power_num')) #add second face
```

This gives an invalid syntax error in the "if" line.

Again, new to Python so I'm not sure about the syntax in checking if "NoneType" is true, or if there's a better way to approach the problem.

If anyone has any advice on how to approach this, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Changed check to `is None` and `keys()` to `get()`. New error is

```
   pow_list.append(x.card_faces[0].get('power_num')
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Minor typo. `if x.card_faces = None:` needs to be `if x.card_faces == None:`. `=` is assignment, `==` is for checking for equality. Also, change `== None` to `is None`, since `None` is a singleton object (although the latter suggestion is more of a best practice).

Comment: That was a lot of writing for a small typo. Thanks for the quick response. I'm glad my approach was valid.

Comment: Is the code formatted properly in the for/if/else block? is this how exactly you have written it, because it lacks identation